# Google maps navigation - get next maneuver

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

Making an info screen for my car.
It's running android and I use google maps for navigation, though I want my own app to somehow mirror the basic directions of maps, so I can view directions among other items (speed, rpm, indicators)

Is there a way I can have my app collect current navigation data from google maps? As in, get the next turn at a given street?

I've tried using android accessibility to watch the notifications,
so when maps is running, my app can get data from the navigation item in the notifications bar, though the AccessibilityEvent only shows basic info, like what android package the notification is from.

Anyone have an idea?

Edit:
To make this clearer, I want to do what this app does:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.batescorp.pebble.nav&hl=en

but instead of sending info to a pebble, send info to my app.